# How can I send a row's property value to p:confirmDialog?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem when I send the column value to controller when I click a button, always selects the last row of the grid. I want to send the rows selected. Actually always selects the last `#{lst.usuario}` value from the datatable when I invoke the `cambioDeClave()` method.

How Can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

```
<p:dataTable id="tabla" var="lst" styleClass="myTable"
             paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
             style="word-break:normal; width:600px;letter-spacing:-0.5px;"
             sortMode="multiple"
             value="#{busquedaUsuariosController.listado}" paginator="true"
             rows="20" .................>

    <p:column headerText="CLAVE" width="48">

        <p:commandButton onclick="confirmacionClave.show()" style="width:40px;"
                         type="button" value="#{lst.usuario}" />

        <p:confirmDialog message="¿Está seguro que desea generar una nueva clave para el usuario? #{lst.usuario}"
                         showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" severity="alert"
                         widgetVar="confirmacionClave">

            <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" update="@form"
                             oncomplete="confirmacionClave.hide()"
                             action="#{busquedaUsuariosController.cambioDeClave(lst.usuario)}" >
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="confirmacionClave.hide()"
                             type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Where is your `<h:form/>` and why is your `<p:dialog/>` nested in your `<p:dataTable/>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selection attribute of the p:datatable. This selection attribute mapped to your managed bean property like this.

```
  <p:dataTable id="tabla" var="lst" styleClass="myTable" 
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" 
                selection="#{busquedaUsuariosController.selectedObject}"............>  your
```

And your managed bean should have a property like this

```
          BusquedaUsuariosController {  
             Type selectedObject //donno what is ur object type here o 

        }
```

and you have to mention your selectionMode="single/multiple". If your selectionMode is multiple then you should map your selection attribute of datatable to an array.

Hope this helps.